# Use multiple letters for shortcut on command key in informix 4GL

Tags: informix, 4gl

I have the following 2 RingMenus:

1. AddOrder
2. AddCustomer

How can I add a shortcut so that I can press "AO" for AddOrder, and "AC" for AddCustomer?

I know we can add shortcuts like:

```
command key("o") "AddOrder" "Add a new order"
```

But how can I make the shortcut to be more than one character?

I am looking for something like this:

```
command key("ac") "AddCustomer" "Add a new customer"
command key("ao") "AddOrder" "Add a new order"
```

But with the above line I'm getting the following error:

> "ac" is not a recognized key value. See error number -4447.

Oh, and by the way:

> Message number -4447 not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Succinctly, you can't.  Menu keys are a single character.

IIRC, you  could experiment with `COMMAND 'ACustomer'` and `COMMAND 'AOrder'`.  The ambiguous first letters mean a 'menu resolution method' is used after you've typed the opening <kbd>a</kbd>, so you'd have to type `C` or `O` (in either upper-case or lower-case) to select the menu option.  You need to keep typing the common leading letters, so 'Add Customer' and 'Add Order' would require <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, <kbd>d</kbd>, before choosing <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>o</kbd>.

On the whole, though, it is simpler and arguably better to strict to unique initial letters for the options in the menu commands.

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
    COMMAND KEY("A") "Add ..." "Add Order/Customer"
        MENU ""
            COMMAND KEY ("O") "Order" "Add Order"
                ...
            COMMAND KEY ("C") "Customer" "Add Customer"
                ...
            COMMAND KEY ("X") "Exit"
                EXIT MENU
        END MENU
```

may also achieve what you were after. Depends how attached you are to having the two adds in the initial ring menu and wether you are thinking of eventually porting to a 4gl GUI product such as FourJs Genero.  My suggestion would result in two clicks in a GUI whilst your original Menu would only require one click.